# Transform multiple categorical columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

In my dataset I have two categorical columns which I would like to numerate. The two columns both contain countries, some overlap (appear in both columns). I would like to give the same number in column1 and column2 for the same country.

My data looks somewhat like:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['NL', 'BE', 'FR', 'BE'], 'col2': ['BE', 'NL', 'ES', 'ES']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Currenty I am transforming the data like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

However this makes no distinction between FR and ES. Is there another simple way to come to the following output?

```
o = {'col1': [2,0,1,0], 'col2': [0,2,4,4]}
output = pd.DataFrame(data=o)
output
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.stack().astype('category').cat.codes.unstack()
Out[190]: 
   col1  col2
0     3     0
1     0     3
2     2     1
3     0     1
```

Or

```
s=df.stack()
s[:]=s.factorize()[0]
s.unstack()
Out[196]: 
   col1  col2
0     0     1
1     1     0
2     2     3
3     1     3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can fit the LabelEncoder() with the unique values in your dataframe first and then transform.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(pd.concat([df.col1, df.col2]).unique()) # or np.unique(df.values.reshape(-1,1))

df.apply(le.transform)
Out[28]: 
   col1  col2
0     3     0
1     0     3
2     2     1
3     0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.unique` with `return_invesere`. Though you then need to reconstruct the DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(df.shape),
             index=df.index,
             columns=df.columns)

   col1  col2
0     3     0
1     0     3
2     2     1
3     0     1
```